# Basic Angularjs routing failing to get template

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to Angular and I want to setup very basic routing. My `cart.html` has the text: "Hello Cart" and by going to #/Step I want to change this to "Hello World".
(My console is not giving me any error messages)

I have: `someurl.com/page` and when I change it to: `someurl.com/page#/Step` nothing happens.

This is the HTML

```
<div class="row" ng-app="ecom">
  <div class="large-12 columns" ng-include="'cart.html'">
    <div ng-view></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the JS

```
var ecom = angular.module('ecom', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource']);

ecom.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
       .when('/Step', {
            template: 'hello world'
       });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the ng-include on the parent div is messing it up.

One way to solve this is to add another route on "/" and set that routes templateUrl to "cart.html"

```js
(function() {
  var ecom = angular.module('ecom', ['ngRoute']);

  ecom.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when("/", {
        template: "hello cart", //remove this line to use cart.html
        templateUrl: "cart.html"
      })
      .when("/step", {
        template: "hello world"
      });
  });


})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0" src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/angular.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular-route@*" data-semver="1.2.20" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-app="ecom">
    <a href="#/step">To Step</a>
    <div>
      <div ng-view>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Also: here is a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/RnEJKR)

Comment: Thanks csmithmaui, that works. However, I don't really understand why the ng-include doesn't work in this manner.

Comment: Hi bvl, you're welcome.  I am actually not sure why on a technical level.  Maybe someone that understands angular a little better could explain it to us.  It *seems* like when you use ng-include, only the html thats located in the template or templateUrl file gets compiled and then replaces the entire ng-include tag. Therefore, wiping out your ng-view.

Comment: Actually, why would one use ng-include at all...?

Comment: The answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20025101/how-to-decide-when-to-use-ngview-or-nginclude gives a clue.  Further, ng-inlcude can be used to keep the code needed to make a single page with multiple sections more modular.  Each section has a template and possibly it's own controller. Then you can ng-include the templates wherever you like in your main page.  Now, if you have code that you are re-using in several areas it might be time to think about a directive at that point though.

Comment: This style-guide doesn't mention this issue specifically. but might come in hand sometime when thinking through how to structure your application. https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide#table-of-contents