# Angular click for new page with infomation from clicked item JSON

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

I have a product page, and there is an option for a 'quick view' which opens the product description and images in a modal. I also have a 'full details' button where I would like the user to be taken to a new URL based on the item code, but also display the information from my JSON for that clicked product. This is what I have:

```
<a ng-click="store.selected = product" ng-href="{{store.selected.code}}.html" class="btn btn-sm">Full details</a>
```

Everything works great for the Modal, so I am presuming there is a problem moving onto a different page and carrying this information across? I have mocked it up in Plunker to show the problem:

[Plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ie213V73biBuamimiCIX?p=preview)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should [consider using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20025101/how-to-decide-when-to-use-ngview-or-nginclude) [ng-route](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) to switch the view to a different html file.  But you can also use [ng-include](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) with a little less set up.

When the `Full details` link is clicked, toggle a variable that tracks whether the gallery or the details should be visible.  And, construct the path to the html template you want to display:

```
$scope.setSelection = function(product) {
  $scope.store.selected = product; 
  $scope.detail.show = !$scope.detail.show; 
  $scope.detail.source = product.code + '.html'
}
```

Then, use `ng-include` to display the template:

```
<div ng-if="detail.show" ng-include="detail.source">
</div>
```

Here is an update of your plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/zhsY6TAjONewyInGiwUC?p=preview

Note that the template should just be a snippet of html.. you don't need to include scripts like `angular` again.