# Not sure when to use ng-view or ng-include

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-view

I have used recently the ng-view in partial view and it looks much like the use of ng-include. Is there a difference between the two: ng-view directive  and  ng-include or when is it better to use which?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to decide when to use ngView or ngInclude?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20025101/how-to-decide-when-to-use-ngview-or-nginclude)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20025101/how-to-decide-when-to-use-ngview-or-nginclude

Answer (score 5):

Basicly ng-View creates a new View which works with States or Routing, saying this view gets his own Controller and Stuff like it would be a html file. And ng-include is if you have like a html template which u need to show on different views and include it to not duplicate code.

So for example you can ng-include your header html where you have your navigation, and you could ng-view a register form or smth where you need it to have its own Route/ State and Controller