# Angularjs Binding Problems for dynamically created elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to bind a `<p>` with an `<input>` in my application, but it is not happening. since both elements are dynamically created, I thought maybe I can use $apply, but it didn't work out.  everything else is functioning as expected except for this. 


My code is a bit complicated, so here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ead1Faf4RnPEaHuDd2x1?p=preview) to demonstrate my situation.


HTML:

```
<body ng-app="tata" ng-controller="mainController">
    <div id="main">
      <div ng-controller="ctrl1">
        <button ng-click="changeCard()">Add Dynamic Bound Elements </button>
        <page id="front" size="A4"></page>
        <div id="detailsFront"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

The elements are generated using 2 functions, on for INPUT and the other for P. Here is where the `input`s are placed:

```
<div id="detailsFront">         
</div>
```

and here where the `p`s are placed:

```
<page size="A4" id="front">
</page>
```

The controller responsible for this view has 2 functions which are run successively in the same `$scope` function. Populating `<p>`s:

```
 buildPDF : function (parentElement){
      var element = angular.element(document.getElementById( parentElement ));
      ele = "<p ng-bind='id7'> Test Run </p>";
      element.append(ele);
    }

    element.append(ele);
```

Then the `input`s:

```
buildPDFControllers : function (parentElement){
          var element = angular.element(document.getElementById( parentElement ));
      ele = "<label for='id7'>Some Label</label> <input name='id7' type='text' ng-model='id7'>";
      element.append(ele); 
        }
```

Comment: You'll need to `$compile(stuff)(scope);` and maybe you should use directives. And plunker would be nice.

Comment: You're right, I updated the question with a Plunker

Comment: Any help from the example, no?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must always `$compile` new elements.

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app="tata">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl1">
    <page id="front"></page>
  </div>
</body>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var app = angular.module('tata', [])

  .controller('ctrl1', function ($scope, $compile) {
    $scope.id = 'some id here';

    var element = angular.element(document.getElementById('front'));
    var p = '<p ng-bind="id">Test Run</p>'; // <- will be bound/replaced with $scope.id
    element.append(p);

    $compile(element.contents())($scope);
  });
```

---

But maybe you'd be better off using directives instead? Consider:

**HTML template**

```
<body ng-app="cards" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <button ng-click="addCard()">Add Card</button>
  <div ng-repeat="card in cards">
    <card ng-model="card"></card>  
  </div>
</body>
```

**JavaScript**

```
angular.module('cards',[])

  .controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.cards = [];

    $scope.addCard = function() {
      var next = $scope.cards.length + 1; 
      $scope.cards.push({id: next, label: next});
    };
  })

  .directive('card', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      require: 'ngModel',
      scope: {
        ngModel: '='
      },
      template: '<p>Directive model: {{ ngModel | json }}</p>' +
                '<label>Label: </label>' + 
                '<input name="{{ ngMode.id }}" ' + 
                '       type="text" ' +
                '       ng-model="ngModel.label">',
      link: function(scope) {
      }
    };
  });
```

---

[image: imgur]

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably be better off using directives for this - and you might not even need to roll your own. Have a look at [`ng-include`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude): it lets you switch which HTML template to use based on a variable in your scope. Something like:

`inputText-view.html`:

```
<p ng-style="style">{{value.content}}</p>
```

`page.html`:

```
<page size="A4" id="front" style="position: absolute, top:0px, left:0px">
    <ng-include
        ng-repeat="value in values"
        src="value.type + '-view.html'"></ng-include>
</page>
```

[See here for a demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/STQnErYeyTdaN0zy49W4?p=preview).

[Here's another demo based on your plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/4lF9mKxAwIqn4FdD3VbT?p=preview).

Comment: @z0r thank you it seems interesting, i didn't know I could use ng-include. Which is more preferable, ng-view or ng-include ?

Comment: @MikkoViitala Fair enough, I was just going by the docs' "Typically, you don't use `ngBind` directly". But you're right; I'll remove that recommendation.

Comment: I updated the question with a plunker, if you can find a solution for that i'll mark it as an accepted answer. + i'll look into the ng-include

Comment: `ng-view` is for changing the active controller and template based on the route. In this case you need `ng-include`.

Comment: can you explain further? what is so special about this situation ?

Comment: Added another demo based on the plunk you provided.

Comment: `ng-view` and `ng-include` perform quite different functions. `ng-view` sets a single template and controller, and changes based on the URL. AFAIK it can only be used once. `ng-include` changes only the template (although the template itself can contain controllers), and changes based on the scope. It can be used many times. In your case, you want to change the template based on the scope and you want to use it many times (probably in `ng-repeat`) so you can't use `ng-view`. [See also this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20025101/how-to-decide-when-to-use-ngview-or-nginclude)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88926/discussion-between-z0r-and-user2517028).

Comment: I like this solution, but it seems too complicated and decentralized + I couldn't work it in my code.
Can you help me understand why my code didn't work ? why isn't angular binding the 2 objects?

Comment: @MikkoViitala is probably right (in the comment on your question) - you need to use `$compile` to bind your HTML elements to the scope.