# ng-view shows weird behaviour with bootstrap data tables

Tags: angularjs, datatables, bootstrap-4, ng-view

I have, for the first time used a ready made template for my project.
Here's the link https://colorlib.com/polygon/adminator/index.html of that theme.

Whenever I am trying to load the datatable of that theme into the `ng-view`, it loads everything except this. 
[image]

Here's the snapshot of that,[image]

But when I am using it normally ( without the using ngView), everything loads fine,
[image]

here's the code snippet of that `index.html` file

```
<main class="main-content bgc-grey-100">
            <!--<h1> ng-view content</h1>-->
            <div ng-view id="mainContent" > <!-- whenever I remove the ngview and just paste the code below in this section, it works fine -->

            </div>

        </main> <!-- main ends --><br><br>
```

and the partial template which I am loading has the following code.

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
            <h4 class="c-grey-900 mT-10 mB-30">Data Tables</h4>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="bgc-white bd bdrs-3 p-20 mB-20">
                  <h4 class="c-grey-900 mB-20">Bootstrap Data Table</h4>
                  <table id="dataTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Position</th>
                        <th>Office</th>
                        <th>Age</th>
                        <th>Start date</th>
                        <th>Salary</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tfoot>
                      <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Position</th>
                        <th>Office</th>
                        <th>Age</th>
                        <th>Start date</th>
                        <th>Salary</th>
                      </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                        <td>System Architect</td>
                        <td>Edinburgh</td>
                        <td>61</td>
                        <td>2011/04/25</td>
                        <td>$320,800</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                        <td>Accountant</td>
                        <td>Tokyo</td>
                        <td>63</td>
                        <td>2011/07/25</td>
                        <td>$170,750</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                        <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                        <td>San Francisco</td>
                        <td>66</td>
                        <td>2009/01/12</td>
                        <td>$86,000</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                        <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                        <td>Edinburgh</td>
                        <td>22</td>
                        <td>2012/03/29</td>
                        <td>$433,060</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>Airi Satou</td>
                        <td>Accountant</td>
                        <td>Tokyo</td>
                        <td>33</td>
                        <td>2008/11/28</td>
                        <td>$162,700</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                        <td>New York</td>
                        <td>61</td>
                        <td>2012/12/02</td>
                        <td>$372,000</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                        <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                        <td>San Francisco</td>
                        <td>59</td>
                        <td>2012/08/06</td>
                        <td>$137,500</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                        <td>Tokyo</td>
                        <td>55</td>
                        <td>2010/10/14</td>
                        <td>$327,900</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
                        <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                        <td>San Francisco</td>
                        <td>39</td>
                        <td>2009/09/15</td>
                        <td>$205,500</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                        <td>Software Engineer</td>
                        <td>Edinburgh</td>
                        <td>23</td>
                        <td>2008/12/13</td>
                        <td>$103,600</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>Jena Gaines</td>
                        <td>Office Manager</td>
                        <td>London</td>
                        <td>30</td>
                        <td>2008/12/19</td>
                        <td>$90,560</td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

I am beginner in AngularJs. I don't how is that happening. This was the best way in which I could have framed out the question. If anything's missing please let ne know. Please help me out in solving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

`ng-view` is usually used for routing. If you want to include a html template inside another page I would recommend using `ng-include`.

`<div ng-include src="'/path/to/the/file.html'"></div>`

NOTE: The file path must be within single quotes as `src` expects a string.

[When to use ng-view and ng-include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20025101/how-to-decide-when-to-use-ngview-or-nginclude)

Comment: sir,  I am using ngView for my SPA for routing purpose, so ng-include won't be helpful in my case.

Comment: Looks like the features are getting turned off. Did you try setting the feature to `true` explicitly? `$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dataTable').DataTable( {
        "search":   true,
        "lengthChange": true,
    } );
} );`